# verdana font on linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts

I'm trying to use the `verdana.ttf` font to create a RTF report with Java, but it isn't working on Linux.

Does anybody know how I do this?

```
     String contextPath = FacesUtil.getServletContext().getRealPath("\\");
     try {
          FontFactory.register(contextPath + "WEB-INF\\Fonts\\verdana.ttf");
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

     if (negrito) {
          font = FontFactory.getFont("Verdana", 8, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0));
     }
     cell = new Cell(new Paragraph(paragraph, font));
            cell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            cell.setBorderColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            if (center)
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Cell.ALIGN_LEFT);

            cell.setRowspan(1);
            cell.setColspan(1);
            return cell;
```

Comment: Define "isn't working." What's your problem, specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if it's not working on Linux it's because you hard-code file separator...

`\\` is only for Windows. Replace those with a field made from [`System.getProperty("file.separator")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Example :

```
String separator  = System.getProperty("file.separator");
FontFactory.register(contextPath + "WEB-INF"+separator+"Fonts"+separator+"verdana.ttf");
```